# Send an ASCII message

Tags: c#, tcpserver

I have a "Sysmex XP-300" machine who sends data via TCP, I need to catch this data and reply with ASCII, to verify that the it was received.
The problem is, that every time the machine is connected, the code will reply "connected" non stop. I also need to reply with ASCII that my machine seems not receive. Here my code:

```
class Program
{
    static string ack = char.ConvertFromUtf32(6);
    byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ack);
    const int PORT_NO = 3001;
    const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpServer tcpServer = new TcpServer(SERVER_IP, 3001);
        tcpServer.Connected += new TcpServer.TcpServerEventDlgt(OnConnected);
        tcpServer.StartListening();
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit the server.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        tcpServer.StopListening();
    }

    static void OnConnected(object sender, TcpServerEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the connection here by starting your own worker thread
        // that handles communicating with the client.
        Console.WriteLine("Connected.");

        IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] bytesToSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ack);// ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

        //---send the text---
        Console.WriteLine("Sending : " );
        nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose your question is about ASCII rather than 'ashii'.

Comment: It seems to me like in OnConnected you are connecting from the server to the server (`TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO)`) and send `ack` to itself rather than to the connected client. That again causes another OnConnect which does the same for an infinite loop of connections. I would assume that the client you're supposed to send to is somewhere in the `TcpServerEventArgs e`.

Comment: if i type:"e.ConnectionState" it appears only: "connection" and "server"